# Не корректно работает $http angular

Tags: php, angularjs, post, get, angularjs-controller

```
$http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : '/api/api.php',
    data: "123",
    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function(res){
    console.log(res);
}).error(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

отправляю такой `get` запрос к php файлику

```
<?php
$myData = json_decode($_POST['myData']);
//echo($myData);
echo("123456123");
?>
```

в консоли получаю `"123456123"` - все хорошо, но если в php заменить цифры и обновить страницу, то в консоли не выведется новых чисел, а выводятся старые. В чем может быть проблема?

При чем, если попытаться открыть php напрямую и потом обновить страницу, в консоль приходят новые цифры, либо открыть с другого браузера сайт, там тоже новые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, отправляю теперь вместо GET запроса POST запрос и все ок